# Django coin/points system ideas

Tags: django

I am creating a Web Based game in django, in which almost all action require some coins/points , So for every action i need to check if userprofile has specific coins for action or not. I have seen Awards/Rewards packages but it seems like they are awarding/rewarding after some action has been performed. I need a generic solution that checks if user has certain coins for an action or not.

for coins i am doing it like this way:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
....
def deduct_coins(coins):
    self.coin -= coins
    self.save()

def has_coins(coins):
    if self.coins >= coins:
       return true
    return false
```

I am not using django forms for all my actions so before each action ( CRUD ) operations i am doing following steps:

- Check if user has required coins
- Perform the action
- Deduct the coins required

1- How can i make this process generic.

2- Are there any custom signals other than builtin signals, if so how can i use them.

3- Can pre_save signal be used for this scenario.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your deduct_coins (and add_coins) methods in a transaction

Comment: @stevejalim can you explain a little bit more.

Comment: If you're not familiar with transactions, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction. If you are, check out the Django specifics: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: so adding `transaction` decorator will rollback any changes in case of exception. will it rollback the `signals` transaction too ?